# How do you execute and external program and it's assocaited command line options using subprocess.call in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I can launch a program using the subprocess call in Python as so:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe'])
```

The above will launch, `VLC` for example.

What's the right syntax to launch a program such as VLC using
`subprocess.call` and add on command line options that would say, run a playlist? (as seen below)

I keep getting error messages in Python when I do the same syntax you'd successfully use in the command prompt.

I have also tried doing the double `\\` in the `--options` segment of the program being run.

For example, let's try launching the playlist option.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe --playlist c:\mydirectory\VideoLan\VLC\playlist.m3u'])
```

```
File "<ipython-input-24-a9b514f42a65>", line 2
subprocess.call(['C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe --playlist c:\mydirectory\VLC\playlist.m3u'])
                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 82-83: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Such syntax would work form the command prompt but not when executing using subprocess.call in Python.

Comment: `call` (and all other functions in `subprocess`) needs string without `[]` if you use `shell=True` - `call('C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe', shell=True)` - or list with splitted elelemts if you don't use `shell=True`- `call(['C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe', '---pplaylist', 'c:\...'])`

Comment: You forgot \\ in `--playlist c:\mydirectory\ ...`. You should use \\ for all \ in command. OR you should use prefix `r` for `raw string`

Comment: Any chance that `c:\mydirectory...` is actually `c:\user...`? If so, then python interprets the `\u` as the start of a unicode escape sequence, which is why you get this error. As already mentioned, doubling all the slashes should fix the problem.

Comment: Adding 'r' and `shell=True` produces a "1" output from Python, but still does not allow for launching  the program with the `--playlist` option as you could from the command prompt.

Comment: It's `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC`

Answer (score 0):

You'd better add r before your path string. That would be treated as raw string.

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe --playlist c:\mydirectory\VLC\playlist.m3u'])
```

Comment: Just adding `r` at the beginning does not allow for launching the program with the `--playlist` tag attached. Still can only launch the program by itself, requesting -- options produces errors.

Answer (score 0):

Char \ has special meaning in string (ie. `\n`, `\t`, `\uCODE`, etc.) even in path and you should use \\ in all places. Or you should use prefix `r` to use `raw string`

---

Other problem is that you run `call` with wrong values.

`call` (and all other functions in `subprocess`) needs

- `string` without `[]` if you use `shell=True`

  ```
   call('C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe --playlist c:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\playlist.m3u', shell=True)

   call(r'C:\mydirectory\VLC\vlc.exe --playlist c:\mydirectory\VLC\playlist.m3u', shell=True)
  ```
- `list` with command splitted to elements if you don't use `shell=True`

  ```
  call(['C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe', '--playlist', 'c:\\...'])

  call([r'C:\mydirectory\VLC\vlc.exe', '--playlist', r'c:\...'])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using subprocess.Popen with spitted elements worked to execute a raw string:

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\mydirectory\\VLC\\vlc.exe', '--playlist-autostart', 'playlist.m3u'])
```